# How to select an image in FCKEditor 2.x using javascript

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, fckeditor

Is there any way to select the image in FCKEditor 2.x using javascript api?

I need select the first image automatically after the editor got focused. The the result should be the same as the user clicked on the image.

Thank you in advance.